# What is the python equivalent to $|=1 in Perl

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, perl, cgi

Hi I'm very new to Perl and CGI.

I'm trying to convert a perl script to python.

It is mentioned **$|=1** in the script. What I understood is it clears the buffer.

I am searching if there is any python equivalent to do the exact thing.

Any suggestions??

Comment: Specifically `$|=1` is equivalent to setting the autoflush property of the currently selected output handle, causing it to flush whenever it's printed to rather than buffering.

Comment: Is there really a point to using `$| = 1;` in a CGI script???

Comment: No Idea why they mentioned **$|=1**. The script was written a decade ago. I'm just trying to convert it to Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd consider not worrying about porting this line for the time being, as flushing stdout after every `print` will likely be the least of your porting worries.

But if it is, you have many options:

- Simply add the `flush=True` keyword argument to your [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function call.
- Run Python in ["unbuffered" mode with the `-u` switch](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u).
- Re-open stdout in unbuffered mode (e.g. the final `0` in):

  - `sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)`
- Write a `print` wrapper function that shadows the builtin `print` and flushes stdout
- Write a `TextIOWrapper` object that wraps `sys.stdout` and flushes

I'll try to find some links for the rest of the points and edit them in.